# How do I skip columns with "NA" without excluding rows?

Tags: r

I'm a student working on a practice problem with a baseball pitching stats data frame in R. Each record includes what pitches that player throws, but not every player throws every type of pitch, resulting in every record having at least one "NA" value. I want to build a linear model to see if certain pitch types influence a player's FIP.

Here's my code:

```
model <- lm(fip ~ fb + sl + ct + cb + ch + spl + kn + other, data = df)
```

I want to skip over columns with "NA" while running the model, but I don't want to exclude the entire row. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some reproducible data? For instance, post the output of `dput(df[1:10,])` to share the first 10 rows of your data. Good luck!

Comment: pass `na.action` argument to the `lm` function. This will determine how to deal with `NA's`

Comment: @Onyambu - which `na.action` will work for a dataset that has at least one NA in every row?

Comment: so they threw 0 of that pitch type, replace the NAs with 0

Comment: @thelatemail `na.action` should be a function. eg you could use `replace(x, is.na(x), 0)` as your `na.action` as suggested by `rawr`.

Comment: I think this question is impossibly vague without more information about the current data structure and a column by column description what is desired in the case of finding an NA. Think about what would happen if you forced 0 values into a column of type “factor” for which a 0 would almost certainly result in errors.